# Cross Web Application Authentication Not Authenticating Unless Redirected From Second Site

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have 2 asp.net web applications using Forms Authentication setup to have cross application authentication. I have placed the following code in webApp1 and webApp2 web.config files within the
system.web tag.

```
<forms timeout="11520" loginUrl="https://App1/logon.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
    protection="All"
    path="/"
    domain="fsenet.companyname.net" />
</authentication>        

<machineKey 
  decryption="AES"
  validation="SHA1"
  decryptionKey="306C1FA852AB3B0115150DD8BA30821CDFD125538A0C606DACA53DBB3C3E0AD2" 
  validationKey="61A8E04A146AFFAB81B6AD19654F99EA7370807F18F5002725DAB98B8EFD19C711337E26948E26D1D174B159973EA0BE8CC9CAA6AAF513BF84E44B2247792265" />
```

Scenario 1 Works: If I try to access a page on webApp2 and I'm un-authenticated it will redirect me back to webApp1 logon page, I then logon and are redirected back to the page on webApp2, All works as expected when using this redirect method.

Scenario 2 Problem: If I Log on using webApp1 and have a link on a page within webApp1 and try to navigate to a page within webApp2 I automatically get redirected back to the logon page. As I understand it I should be already authenticated to access the page on webApp2 and should not be asked to authenticate again.

I use this code to identify if I'm authenticated

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString()
```

Scenario 2 shows False reason for redirection and Scenario 1 shows True.

Am I missing some setting that allows me to access the content on webApp2 after Authenticating with webApp1?

Answer (score 0):

It is very important that you set FBA settings correctly for cross-application SSO. There are already blog posts covering such tricks, and I can see that you missed multiple steps, and then one app cannot get the authenticated info from another.

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/09/03/single-sign-on-across-.net-web-apps-using-forms-based-authentication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I was doing wrong was not access both sites with the same domain e.g. while I was debugging I was logging in via 
http:/localhost/Site1 
(localhost being the mistake) and then linking from their to http://domianname.net/Site2/Page1.aspx when I should have been accessing them both via http://domianname.net/Site1 and http://domianname.net/Site2/Page1.aspx (Both the with the domain) which allows the authentication cookie to be picked up from the correct location I believe.